# Passing type arguments into a custom hook

Tags: typescript, web, react-hooks, next.js

I'm making a nextjs application and I created a custom useAxios hook, I want to be able make a type assertion like you can do with useState:

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState<string>('');
```

But instead I want to pass the type of the response:

```
const { data, error } = useAxios<CustomResponseType>(URL, true);
```

How I can accept this type arguments in my function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type signature will look something like this:

```
const useAxios = <T>(URL: string, something: boolean): { data: T, error: any } => {
   // insert code here
}
```

This is making use of [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @JakubKlimek don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't accept it before and I had to wait and I just forgot about it.